Prove $P(x)=x^{2022}+a_{2021}x^{2021}+a_{2020}x^{2020}+\dots+a_1x+1$ can not have $2022$ real distinct roots

Let $P(x)=x^{2022}+a_{2021}x^{2021}+a_{2020}x^{2020}+\dots+a_1x+1$ with $a_i \in \mathbb{R}, \forall i = \overline{1,2021}$ such that $|a_{1011}|<2$ and $a_{k}=a_{2022-k},\forall k = \overline{1,1011}$. Prove that $P(x)$ can not have $2022$ real distinct roots.

Here is what I tried:
Suppose that $P(x)$ have at least $2022$ real distinct roots are $x_1,x_2,\ldots,x_{2022}$
If $x_j$ is a root of $P(x)$, $\dfrac{1}{x_j}$ is also a root of $P(x)$
Thus $\dfrac{1}{x_n}=x_m$ for some $(m,n)$
Using Vieta theorem: $x_1x_2\ldots x_{1011}+x_2x_3\ldots x_{1012} + \ldots + x_{1011}x_{1012}\ldots x_{2022}=(-1)^{2022}\dfrac{a_{1011}}{1}=a_{1011}$
But from here I can't show any contradiction, can anyone help me from here please, thanks!

I guess you need to show that $a_{1011}$ is in the form $b+\frac1b$ for some $b\neq0$.

A related question: What is the maximum number of real roots in the interval (0,1) of a monic polynomial with integer coefficients and has degree 2022 Why have polynomials of order $2022$ become popular in recent days? :)

As you observed, the roots of $P(x)$ can be divided into pairs $x_1, \dots, x_{1011}$ and $\frac{1}{x_1}, \dots, \frac{1}{x_{1011}}$. Then we have
$$P(x) = \prod_{i = 1}^{1011} (x - x_i) \cdot \prod_{i = 1}^{1011} (x - x_i^{-1}).$$
Set $Q(x) = \prod_{i = 1}^{1011} (x - x_i) = x^{1011} + b_{1010} x^{1010} + \cdots + b_0$. Then we can show
$$\prod_{i = 1}^{1011} (x - x_i^{-1}) = x^{1011} + \frac{b_1}{b_0}x^{1010} + \cdots + \frac{b_{1010}}{b_0}x^1 + \frac{1}{b_0}.$$
Thus we have
$$a_{1011} = \frac{1}{b_0} \left(1 + b_0^2 + b_1^2 + \cdots + b_{1010}^2\right).$$
If all the roots of $P$ are real, then all the $b_i$'s are real, so
$$|a_{1011}| \geq \frac{1 + b_0^2}{|b_0|} \geq 2.$$

This is a very elegant solution (+1). I wonder if we can extend this answer to find the true maximal lower bound of $|a_{1010}|$?

@LNT $b_0$ is the highest degree polynomial in the $x_i$, so if all the $x_i=c$ and $c\rightarrow \infty$, then it dominates the sum and the first inequality in the last line is (asymptotically) tight. However the second one is tight if and only if $b_0=1$. So you'll have to combine the two inequalities to get anywhere.
